# Android camera HAL V3 settings effecting panorama operation

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am doing camera HAL V3 development in lollipop and while running below camera app then switching to panorama is crashing on start. 
I am using android goldfish camera implementation as reference.

com.google.android.GoogleCamera-2.4.008_(1519572-30)-24008130-minAPI19.apk

Interestingly, If I capture an image (with exif metadata) before starting panorama then it works fine.

I have few queries regarding panorama:

are there some settings in camera HAL V3 which effect panorama operation ?

does this camera app uses some configuration parameter which it might be finding in jpeg exif metadata ?

What settings or property I need to set so that panorama feature is not visible in application ?